# SQL Server like statement issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. Now I have two patterns to implement the same function (to see if zoo1 or zoo2 or zoo3 column contains some text, in pattern 1, I merge content of zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3 to form a new column called zoo), I think the first pattern is always of better performance (I have made some experiment) from my experiment. But I am not sure whether I am correct, and what is the internal reason why pattern 1 is always of better performance?

Pattern 1:

```
Select foo, goo from tablefoo where zoo like LIKE '%'+@Query+'%'
```

Pattern 2 (zoo is a column which I merge the content of column zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3 to generate):

```
Select foo, goo from tablefoo where (zoo1 like LIKE '%'+@Query+'%') OR (zoo2 like LIKE '%'+@Query+'%') or (zoo3 like LIKE '%'+@Query+'%')
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: How are you constructing the combined column, `zoo`? Are you using a view, and if so, is it indexed? Are you using a computed column, and if so, is it persisted? BTW, your query may be vulnerable to SQL-Injection attacks.

Comment: I answered a similar question to this already this week http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649673/what-indices-should-be-created-to-optimize-sql-query-with-multiple-or-conditions/3656415#3656415 SQL Indices pretty much fall over with queries Or a or b or c its better to do unions and seperate queries

Comment: @Daniel In what way is it vulnerable to Sql Injection?

Comment: @Denis: Now I take a second look, I fail to see a SQL injection problem; as I'm sure you spotted, there's no way to "break out" of the `LIKE` clause pattern value

Comment: Changed tags: applies to all SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR almost always kills performance.

In this case, it's 3 columns to scan vs 1 column to scan.

In both cases, because you have a leading % then an index won't be used anyway (it may be scan because it's covers the zoo% columns)

The 1 column is merely less bad than the 3 column OR query. Not "better".

Comment: So, conclusion is a little improvement of using no OR?

Comment: @George: in this case, yes. In other cases, it probably would be better

Comment: Using leading % is not using index, why?

Comment: @George: Indexes are sorted by the key value(s) and an index seek takes advantage of the sort sequence to find the data.  For example, if 'Zoo%' is greater than 'M', SQL Server doesn't have to look at values less than or equal to 'M'.  By putting a leading %, you're telling SQL Server to find values that begin with 'A' or 'Z', or any valid character.  SQL Server must check all values, which defeats the advantage of the index.